# Sending a message to 'self' causes initialize method to be called?

Tags: ruby, oop

I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
require 'pry-byebug'
require 'fileutils'

class Foo < Pathname
  include FileUtils
  def initialize(path)
    puts "Inside Foo init..."
    super
    puts "Side effect happening..."
  end

  def some_method
    puts "Inside some_method inside Foo..."
    basename.to_s
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

bar = Bar.new('bar')
# binding.pry
bar.some_method
```

This is the output:

```
Inside Foo init...
Side effect happening...
Inside some_method inside Foo...
Inside Foo init...
Side effect happening...
```

As you can see the "side effect" is happening twice. Taking a look at a `pry-byebug` session confirms:

```
Inside Foo init...
Side effect happening...

From: /Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/super_test/foo.rb @ line 23 :

    18: class Bar < Foo
    19: end
    20:
    21: bar = Bar.new('bar')
    22: binding.pry
 => 23: bar.some_method

[1] pry(main)> step

From: /Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/super_test/foo.rb @ line 13 Foo#some_method:

    12: def some_method
 => 13:   puts "Inside some_method inside Foo..."
    14:   basename.to_s
    15: end

[1] pry(#<Bar>)> step
Inside some_method inside Foo...

From: /Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/super_test/foo.rb @ line 14 Foo#some_method:

    12: def some_method
    13:   puts "Inside some_method inside Foo..."
 => 14:   basename.to_s
    15: end

[1] pry(#<Bar>)> step

From: /Users/max/Dropbox/work/tmp/super_test/foo.rb @ line 7 Foo#initialize:

     6: def initialize(path)
 =>  7:   puts "Inside Foo init..."
     8:   super
     9:   puts "Side effect happening..."
    10: end
```

So breaking it down:

1. I instantiate `bar` which is an instance of `Bar` which inherits from `Foo`. `Bar`'s superclass' `initialize` is called and the "side effect" happens. So far this is totally expected.
2. I call `some_method` on `bar` who doesn't have it so ruby goes up and to the right and finds it inside of `Foo`
3. Ruby hops inside of `some_method` and finds a method that's sending a message to `self` called `basename`
4. Ruby goes back to `Foo`'s' `initialize` method?...

Step 4 is catching me completely by surprise. Why would sending a message to `self` cause the initialize method to get called again? Is this documented anywhere? Is this expected?

Is it possible to control this? Or conditionally check if I'm inside the initialize method because I'm actually instantiating a class and not just randomly landing there? For example:

```
class Foo < SomeClass
  def initialize args
    @args = args
    if instantiating_a_class?
      puts "Side effect happening..."
    else
      puts "Don't do anything..."
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would sending a message to self cause the initialize method to get called again? Is this documented anywhere? Is this expected?

That's how `basename` is implement, it returns a new instance:

```c
/*
 * Returns the last component of the path.
 *
 * See File.basename.
 */
static VALUE
path_basename(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)
{
    VALUE str = get_strpath(self);
    VALUE fext;
    if (rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &fext) == 0)
        str = rb_funcall(rb_cFile, rb_intern("basename"), 1, str);
    else
        str = rb_funcall(rb_cFile, rb_intern("basename"), 2, str, fext);
    return rb_class_new_instance(1, &str, rb_obj_class(self));
}
```

The last line is equivalent to calling `new`.

You can verify this easily:

```
class Foo < Pathname
  def initialize(path)
    puts "initialize(#{path.inspect})"
    super
  end
end

foo = Foo.new('foo/bar/baz')
# prints initialize("foo/bar/baz")
#=> #<Foo:foo/bar/baz>

foo.basename
# prints initialize("baz")
#=> #<Foo:baz>
```

Comment: What's interesting is it respects the class rather than being fixed on `Pathname`.

Comment: I'm not even sure that's intended. It could also be a side-effect of just passing `rb_obj_class(self)` as the class argument to `rb_class_new_instance`. IOW: it may not be "respecting" so much as "the lazy way to implement".

Answer (score 2):

As you said it has to do with `basename` method. As it can be seen in the source code of the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-basename), `basename` instantiates another object of the class.

Answer (score 2):

[Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) instance methods usually return Pathname instances. To do so, they need to call `initialize` on the current class.

If you look at the sourcecode of [`basename`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-basename) :

```
 return rb_class_new_instance(1, &str, rb_obj_class(self));
```

If it's not the desired functionality of your `Foo` and `Bar` classes, you could stop inheriting from `Pathname`, and define a `@pathname` instance variable.

Finally, you probably don't want to create directories automatically in `initialize` as you proposed yesterday :

Getting the basename of `file.txt` could create a `file` directory.

Answer (score 2):

> Step 4 is catching me completely by surprise. Why would sending a message to self cause the initialize method to get called again? Is this documented anywhere? Is this expected?

Well, yes. Methods are allowed to call other methods. That's pretty much the whole point of methods. [`basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-basename) returns a new `Pathname` object. So, how do you think it constructs this new `Pathname` object? Of course, it calls `self.class::new` (which is actually [`Class#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new)) which in turn calls [`Pathname#initialize`](https://github.com/rubysl/rubysl-pathname/blob/2.0/lib/rubysl/pathname/pathname.rb#L228-L242).

[This is what the implementation of `Pathname#basename` looks like in Rubinius's implementation of the Ruby standard libraries](https://github.com/rubysl/rubysl-pathname/blob/2.0/lib/rubysl/pathname/pathname.rb#L876):

> ```
> def basename(*args) self.class.new(File.basename(@path, *args)) end
> ```

The implementation of `Class#new` looks roughly like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    # allocate a new empty object from the ObjectSpace
    obj = allocate

    # initialize it (must use send because initialize is private)
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)

    # return object that was initialized
    obj
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it calls `self.class::new`"? It makes sense to me what's going on. `self` is the object I'm inside so in this case `self.new #=> Foo` which is like `Foo.new`. But is the `self.class::new` a pattern that methods use to start the process of returning a new instance of themselves?

Comment: That's a common pattern of returning a new instance of the same class, yes. See, for example [Rubinius's implementation of the `pathname` library](https://github.com/rubysl/rubysl-pathname/blob/2.0/lib/rubysl/pathname/pathname.rb#L876), which I find much more readable than YARV's, which a couple of other answerers posted.